# __VA_ARGS__ for code generation

Tags: c++

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
#define IID(x)   if (iid == x::iid()) {return true;}
#define CAST_LIST(...) \
    bool isCastable(unit iid) { __VA_ARGS__ return false;}
```

Want to use a pair of macros to generate code for a function where each argument contributes an if statement.

**VA_ARGS** expansion is inserting commas.   My question is that OK?  I hardly ever use the comma operator in C++.  I call it as follows:

```
CAST_LIST( \
    IID(ClassA), IID(ClassB))
```

Preprocessed file looks like this:

```
bool isCastable(unit iid) { if (iid == ClassA::iid()) {return true;}, if (iid == ClassB::iid()) {return true;} return false;}
```

Comment: Can you show how you call it?

Comment: Retired Ninja, just added the info you wanted.

Comment: Any reason you even need `__VA_ARGS__` here? `#define CAST_LIST(params) bool isCastable(unit iid) { params return false;}` + `CAST_LIST(IID(ClassA) IID(ClassB))` looks like it should work.

Comment: etheranger, thanks! I didn't think of that even though I used to do things that way.   This works (you have to exclude the commas in the call which is fine).   I am still curious if __VA_ARGS__ is useful for anything other than passing off parameters to printf().